# Does an IC package type have same dimensions regardless of who manufactures it?

Tags: integrated-circuit, eaglecad, packages

There are numerous IC package types, popular ones being DIP, QFP, SOIC e.t.c and they have variations depending on how many pins they have

I am designing my Eagle library and have a question. Is it always safe that e.g I need a SOIC8 package that I can copy the package from any other library containing SOIC8 or is it possible that a SOIC8 chip from one manufacturer shall be slightly different from SOIC8 from another manufacturer making the library parts incomptible?

Comment: They are close but not necessarily the same. There are tolerances.

Comment: thanks, that is what my question is about. Do I need to worry about tolerances since I have a list of parts that I need to create in Eagle.

Comment: If you have specific parts, look at their datasheets for exact dimensions.

Comment: There's at least three standard widths for SOIC8; 150 mils, 220 mils and 300 mils...

Comment: @PkP I guess (well, hope) the question here is about one specific width..

Comment: @EugeneSh, Just pointing out an obvious... just for him to perhaps consider using package names such as SO8-150 and SO8-300 for example. I work for an IC manufacturer and more than once our customers haven't realized this and had to fix their boards... I thought it would be helpful to give this remark.

Comment: Even if the packages are the same, footprint recommendations may not be, even from products from the same manufacturer (i.e. 0603 MLCCs vs resistors, soldering process, etc..)

Comment: @WesleyLee, that's correct. For example different ICs from us that are all in a similar QFN package have different requirements for the thermal pad underneath the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's a multitude of different variations for pin pitches and package sizes, thermal pad geometries and so on that can make packages incompatible. For a similarly named LQFP or QFN package, for example, the pin pitch might be 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.65 or 0.8 millimeters and the outline of the plastic could be, for example 7x7, 10x10 or 12x12 millimeters.

Below is an example of one of many pages of dimensions describing various LQFP variants from a single chip packager:
[image]

So there are a lot of variants. Also you must take into account the different thermal pad layout requirements for different ICs. It saves a lot of trouble to include the thermal pad layout in a package rather than expect the user to dig through datasheets to get it right.

But if you get the dimension variant correct, e.g. LFQP52 at 10x10 package, with pitch of 0.65 mm, then I guess it doesn't matter which factory makes the chip.. the pins should be all center aligned, for example.

Answer (score 0):

We've never had a problem for board layout as far as pad placement goes.  However, we have noticed that the plastic part of the SOIC package varies in length and component height between manufacturers, as well as the way of marking pin one (beveled edge vs. dot).  We do all hand solder here, so I'm not sure how close the bodies can be when doing automatic placement.